# PHP Require causes error 500...only sometimes. What is this an error from?

Tags: php, path, require

I have a website and it connects to a mysql database and it uses some other passwords that are defined in a file located in /home/user/public_html/inc/instance-config.php.

I want to keep my passwords above the /public_html directory for security. Basically I made a file called **/home/user/secrets.php** and the main config file should require this file and get the passwords from it. 
But it doesn't.

This code in my file **/home/user/public_html/inc/instance-config.php** gives no errors:

```
$secrets = str_replace ( 'public_html', '', getcwd() )  . 'secrets.php';

if ( file_exists( $secrets ) ){
    include $secrets ;
}

**// confirm that the values where imported**
moo( 'The secret value is ' . $secret_value );

$config['db']['type'] = 'mysql';
$config['db']['server'] = 'localhost';
$config['db']['database'] = 'xxxxxxx';
$config['db']['user'] = 'xxxxxxx';

$config['db']['password'] = 'xxxxxxx';
$config['cookies']['mod'] = 'xxxxxxxx';
$config['cookies']['salt'] = 'xxxxxx';
```

My file **secrets.php** has the same last seven lines with the configuration and passwords, and a variable called "**secret_value**" which I use basically to check that the file has been included correctly. So, I do this, and since my "**moo**" function outputs to a log file, I get something like:

```
03/28/2013 07:36:52 am -- The secret value is Everything OK!
03/28/2013 07:36:55 am -- The secret value is Everything OK!
03/28/2013 07:36:55 am -- The secret value is Everything OK!
03/28/2013 06:36:56 am -- The secret value is Everything OK!
03/28/2013 07:36:57 am -- The secret value is Everything OK!
03/28/2013 06:36:57 am -- Rebuilt page 1 from ALL
03/28/2013 07:36:57 am -- The secret value is Everything OK!
03/28/2013 06:36:58 am -- The secret value is Everything OK!
03/28/2013 06:36:58 am -- The secret value is Everything OK!
03/28/2013 06:36:58 am -- The secret value is Everything OK!
03/28/2013 06:36:58 am -- The secret value is Everything OK!
03/28/2013 06:36:58 am -- The secret value is Everything OK!
03/28/2013 06:36:58 am -- The secret value is Everything OK!
03/28/2013 06:36:58 am -- The secret value is Everything OK!
03/28/2013 06:36:58 am -- The secret value is Everything OK!
03/28/2013 06:36:58 am -- The secret value is Everything OK!
03/28/2013 06:36:59 am -- The secret value is Everything OK!
03/28/2013 06:36:59 am -- The secret value is Everything OK!
03/28/2013 06:36:59 am -- The secret value is Everything OK!
03/28/2013 06:36:59 am -- The secret value is Everything OK!
03/28/2013 06:36:59 am -- The secret value is Everything OK!
03/28/2013 06:36:59 am -- The secret value is Everything OK!
03/28/2013 06:36:59 am -- The secret value is Everything OK!
03/28/2013 06:36:59 am -- The secret value is Everything OK!
03/28/2013 06:36:59 am -- The secret value is Everything OK!
03/28/2013 07:36:59 am -- The secret value is Everything OK!
```

So, it seems that the file is being required correctly. I tried to delete those lines from my instance-config file, so that they only appear in the secret.php file. But first, I tried to branch the code, checking for the existence of the file. If the file exists, then it should get the configuration variables from it. This is my code:

```
    moo(':: GET READY');
if ( file_exists( $secrets ) ){
    require $secrets ;
    if ( isset ($secret_value) )
        moo( 'The secret value is ' . $secret_value);
    else
        moo('Required but could not find the secret value');
}else{
    $config['db']['type'] = 'mysql';
    $config['db']['server'] = 'localhost';
    $config['db']['database'] = 'xxxxxx';
    $config['db']['user'] = 'xxxxxxxx';
    $config['db']['password'] = 'xxxxxxxxxx';
    $config['cookies']['mod'] = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx';
    $config['cookies']['salt'] = 'xxxxxxxxx';
    moo( 'The secret value was not obtained');
}
```

And oh yes, I get a list of output lines like:

```
03/28/2013 07:41:07 am -- :: GET READY ::
03/28/2013 07:41:07 am -- The secret value is Everything OK!
```

And every "GET READY" is followed by the correspondent "Everything is OK!". Nowhere in the log file i see a "The secret value was not obtained" or "Required but could not find..." line.

**However**:

In the browser, I get an **Error 500** message and the page stops loading. Why, oh why? I've checked the Internet, and most people say it could be a problem with PHP not finding your file. I've tried to help the code locate the file as much as I can:

```
    // this adds /home/user to the include path, because secret.php
    // is located at /home/user/secret.php

if ( false == strpos( ini_get('include_path'), exec('echo ~') ) ) {
    ini_set('include_path', ini_get('include_path') . ':' . exec('echo ~') );
}

    // log errors to see if we can find the cause of the problem
ini_set('log_errors', 1);
ini_set('error_log', '/home/user/errors.log');
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);

    // get absolute path of the file
$secrets = str_replace ( 'public_html', '', getcwd() )  . 'secreto.php';
```

And nothing works, always the same 500 error. What can I do? I've tried almost everything. The file seems to be located properly, as indicated by the output that I got during all the executions. Yet the server gives me an Error 500 page.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you also checked the server (Apache?) error log file?

Comment: On a side note `file_exists()` is not really reliable, as it will return true, if you pass a directory name. Better use `is_file()`.

Comment: but isn't the fact that the code finds the value for "secret_value" which is part of the file, proof enough that the file is being included correctly? Why 500?

Comment: Try to set ini_set values for logging errors FIRST in the file. My guess is that it is the exec()-function that is the problem. What is the purpose of exec('echo ~')?

Comment: exec('echo ~') displays the home directory for the user, in this case /home/user, that's where the secret.php file is located. I've tried setting the name of the file directly in the require function, as require('/home/user/secret.php'); but that doesn't fix the problem. 
The file with the code is included from other files, could this be a problem? It's like this: functions.php calls a function that requires the instance-config.php, and instance-config requires the file secret.php. Can there be require calls inside a required file?

Answer (score 1):

Did you see what is the php error? Error 500 is webserver/apache says php has a problem. 
The problem itself most likely is in webserver/apache error_log file.

Alternatively, run your php file from command line(`php -l somefile.php` can do syntax check) and php would tell you the problem (syntax or runtime), run the file from the same dir you are hosting it like `php somefile.php`.

Comment: No, there is nothing in /home/user/errors.log. Instance-config.php is basically a long list of configuration variables, I don't think there are any routines inside.

Comment: Not your custom error log file - i suggest you remove that code too. I meant the webserver error log file. If its Apache webserver you are using, there is always a error log file in `/var/log/apache/error_log` or similar name.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. The server doesn't have a /var/log/apache directory. On a side note, I accidentally erased my old php.ini and I created a new one with a few basic directives, and now I get an "Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 76 bytes) in /home/user/public_html/inc/database.php on line 56"

This happened when I simply added a "require('home/user/secrets.php)" directive in the configuration file. Maybe after fixing the memory allocation error i'll get the old 500. What other things could cause a 500 error when using require?

Comment: Just checked on my SSH, I did a "ps faux" to see how many processes I run: usually two or three results. However, after changing the code to require the "secrets.php" file, I suddenly got a lot of processes called "api2.php", this file is just a file I used to find information about certain parts of the website. But this does not happen unless I include the require call.

EDIT: I SOLVED THE PROBLEM. It was just that one of the passwords had a character "ñ". Yes. That was the whole problem. Changed that to "n", updated the files...PROBLEM SOLVED! jesus.